# How to develop Russian pages

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am developing a multilanguage website but I have a big problem with Russian language.
I need to create a php page with an html form to save data into a mysql db. I'm writing this code with Notepad++ and when I paste russian word into my code I display "???" instead of my russian word:

e.g. I should have

```
 ...
    Type of Transaction:
    <select name="typetranscation">
      <option value="Аренда">Аренда</option>
      <option value="Продажа">Продажа</option>
    </select><br><br>
   ...
```

But, in fact, I have:

```
Type of Transaction:
        <select name="typetransaction">
          <option value="?????">?????</option>
          <option value="?????">?????</option>
        </select><br><br>
```

What Can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Set your encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click encoding and choose UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the correct charset in head tag of your page

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  .
  .
</head>
```

Comment: This answer deals with output.  The problem was on input.